# export chinese, japanese character in .csv file + mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, export-to-csv, chinese-locale

I am using following code to export the content to .cvs file
which also support chinese and japanese characters.

```
public ActionResult Download(strng accnumber)
{
     string csvContent = "东西，东西，东西, hi";
     var data = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(csvContent );
     string filename = "CSV_" + accnumber + ".csv";
     return File(data, "text/csv", filename);
}
```

when i export my file i am not getting proper chinese or japanese characters. what is missing?

i have used UTF32 encoding to support it.

**Edited**:

i have noticed that opening my .csv file in notepad shows perfect characters but ms-excel doesn't.

Comment: Can you have a look under Excel Options, in the section Advanced there is under General a button Web Options... If you can influence the encoding Excel uses than that is your chance. I belive the weboptions dialog is also avialble from the Tools button op the file open dialog.

Comment: i have tried to set encoding under weboptions to Unicode(Big-Endian) but it's not working for me

Answer (score 2):

I am also got same problem, solve it by using UTF-8-BOM.

`Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble().Concat(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringData)).ToArray()`

Answer (score 1):

As you are on asp.net serving that file you also have to deal with the encoding of the http pipleline. I din't spot that earlier, sorry.

Instead of having a plain ActionResult you should use one of the derived ActionResults, I've used [FileContentResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). Please pay note to the special ContentType I'm constructing to tell the browsers an UTF-32 file is coming...

```
public ActionResult Download(string accnumber)
{
        string csvContent = "东西，东西，东西, hi";
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvContent);
        // add byte order mark
        var bom = new byte[] { 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF };
        // hold it all
        var all = new byte[bom.Length + data.Length];
        // copy over BOM
        Array.Copy(bom, all, bom.Length);
        // copy over data
        Array.Copy(data, 0, all, bom.Length, data.Length);

        string filename = "CSV_" + accnumber + ".csv";
        var file = new FileContentResult( all, "text/csv" )
        {
            FileDownloadName = filename
        };

        return file;    
}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution by changing `ContentType=text/csv;charset=UTF-32` but won't work for me.

Comment: In notepad the results are still OK?

Comment: Added a BOM marker to convice Excel this is an UTF-8 file, verified and works on my box...please verify if a different charset is the default on the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem too. I fix it by adding the following line just before "return file ;" and it works for me.

```
Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html;charset=utf-8>");
return file;
```